# Why does functools reduce function not work with custom object in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, methods

I want to use functools reduce on a custom object that is just a wrapper for a numpy array

```py
class Position:

    def __init__(self, *args, default_val=0., dtype=np.float32):
        self.pos: np.ndarray = np.array(args, dtype=dtype).flatten()
```

I override __add__

```py
    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.pos + other.pos
```

When I want to reduce it, it only works with a max of 2 objects

```py
reduce(op.add, [pos1, pos2]) # works
```

If I add another object to the list like so

```py
reduce(op.add, [pos1, pos2, pos3]) # doesn't work
```

I get the error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'Position'"

Is there another special methods I need to override?

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]? It looks like the problem is that ``Position.__add__``  returns an ``ndarray``, not a ``Position`` – but that should lead to a different error.

Comment: Your `__add__` implementation doesn't return a `Position`.

Comment: Yes that was the issue, once I changed it to return Position it is working now, thanks